# Find unhandled exception in windows service OnStart

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging

I have a selfhosting WCF service which consists of a dll and a Windows service. In the dll my wcf service and app.config are described. The wcf service is meant to host the whole thing.

My Problem is when I try to start the Service now it wont start. "Your Service has been started and then stopped" kind of thing.

I tried to search the error by outcommenting some code. I did it until there was just the structure (Initialisation, onstart, onstop) and even then it didn't work?

Is this something that happens more often? System.Diagnostics.Debbuger.Launch doesn't work to Debug. Has someone better ideas of Debugging the OnStart method?

Comment: Did you check Event Viewer? Also without code, It is very difficult to speculate what might be issue

Comment: 1. Use `Thread.Sleep()` to pause the start of your Windows service, so that you can use Visual Studio to attach to the process during startup. 2. Use WCF tracing to capture WCF exceptions, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Add logging to your application, including of unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Add try...catch in 'OnStart' method with logging to the event log and see if you receive any exceptions.

There is also a chance that some problems might exist in your WCF binding or Service Contract implementation. So, please check the WCF config as well for issues. If you can post the contents of the config, it would be better to give more guidance.

For a quick troubleshooting, you can host the WCF in a console application and see if it is working fine rather than starting the service every time.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Thread.Sleep(milliseconds) in 'OnStart' method, set 'break' on the next line, and attach debugger(alt+ctrl+p in vs) to debug it, if service breaks before reaching break point - should be config file issue, please post it here.

Comment: What I don't get. When I remove ALL references that I added (WCF & a dll) I reset the App.config file and delete everything except initialisation onstart and onstop it still makes the same error

Comment: There is two ways to go: share the project you have or if it's a small project you can compare project structure and files content with an empty new project, if it's an old big project you can compare your changes with working copy in repository.